# $CW$ topology on $X \times Y$ coincides with the product topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I think I heard somewhere that for $X,Y$ (both $CW$ complex) endowing the $CW$ complex $X \times Y$ with its [weak topology](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/CW+complex) is equivalent to endowing $X \times Y$ with the usual [product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology).

Is this result true?

It's certainly true when $Y=[0,1]$, often use in proofs involving continuity of homotopies from $CW$ complex. I'd be interested in references or proofs, any help would be appreciated, thanks in andvance.

Comment: This is true if one of the factors is locally compact or if both have at most countably many cells, but fails in general. You can find this is the Hatcher appendix.

Comment: @Thorgott Theorem $A.6$ p.$5.24$ in Hatcher, thanks. If you want to answer with reference I accept the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\textbf{Theorem:}$ Let $X$ and $Y$ be CW complexes. Then $X \times Y$ is a CW complex **if and only if** one of the following holds:

$(1)$ Either $X$ or $Y$ is locally finite.

$(2)$ Either $X$ or $Y$ has countably many cells in each connected component, and the other has fewer than $\mathfrak b$ many cells in each connected
component.

$\bullet$ For a proof  of the Theorem  and the definitions of the locally finite, the cardinal $\mathfrak b($called the bounding number, and $\aleph_1\leq \mathfrak b\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$$)$ see $\text{Theorem 1}$, and $\text{Definition 7}$, $\text{Definition 3}$; respectively of this paper [PRODUCTS OF CW COMPLEXES by
ANDREW D. BROOKE-TAYLOR](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.05296.pdf).

---

$\bullet$ Now, I will quote some portions of the book [The Topology of CW Complexes by A.T. Lundell, S. Weingram](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/The_Topology_of_CW_Complexes/7FXtBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0).

Let $X_1, X_2$ be two CW-complexes and $X_1 \otimes X_2$ denote the space for which the underlying set is the product $X_1 \times X_2$ and the topology is the weak topology with respect to the product cells. Then $X_1 \otimes X_2$ is a CW complex.

$\textbf{Proposition 5.1.}$ The identity map $\text{Id}\colon X_1\otimes X_2\to Χ_1\times X_2$ is a continuous bijection. Thus the spaces $X_1\otimes X_2$ and $X_1 \times X_2$ differ only in that the CW topology may be finer than the product topology.

$\textbf{Theorem 5.2.}$ If at least one of the two CW-complexes has only countably many cells, or one of the two CW-complexes has finitely many cells, then $\text{Id}\colon X_1\otimes X_2\to Χ_1\times X_2$ is a homeomorphism. Thus the CW topology and the product topology on the product set $X_1 \times  X_2$ coincide in this case.

$\textbf{Corollary 5.3.}$ A subset $K \subseteq X \otimes Y$ is compact **if and only if** it is compact in $X \times Y$.

---

$\textbf{Fact:}$ Let $X_1,X_2$ be two CW-complexes, then $\text{Id}\colon X_1\otimes X_2\to Χ_1\times X_2$ is a CW-approximation, i.e., given any $(x, y) \in X \times Y$ the induced map $\pi_n(\text{Id})\colon\pi_n \big(X \otimes Y , (x, y)\big) \to \pi_n \big(X \times Y, (x, y)\big)$ is an isomorphism for all $n\geq 1$.

To prove this fact, one needs to use the above $\text{Theorem 5.2.}$ and $\text{Corollary 5.3.}$